# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED - Localhost:8080, firebaseID seems involved

Tags: firebase, authentication, connection, connection-refused

> I have a problem trying to connect my firebase with mongoDB, which I got the code right with connections working, tried using SwaggerUI to post and get and its fine. Firebase also stores the right information, however first I got a Cors error were Cors refused connection (I changed to http//:localhost/8080/ and it started working.) Now instead I get a `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` in the chrome console and I can't seem to understand why it is refusing my connection. Tried using this is the Terminal: `echo OK > /dev/tcp/localhost/8080` and got:

`connect: Connection refused
/dev/tcp/localhost/8080: Connection refused`

> Edit: Ok so from network tab in console it seems I am getting some kind of firebaseID connection error:

```
GET http://localhost:8080//profiles/users/by-firebase-id/W4ucZtMTafPMBLxKur8m6C6h3gG2 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

> Here is some of the code with fetch and firebaseID:

```
async getById(id: string): Promise<UserDto> {
    const fetchedUser = await this.userModel.findById(id);
    if (fetchedUser == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return UserDto.fromDocument(fetchedUser);
}

async getByFirebaseId(firebaseId: string): Promise<UserDto> {
    const fetchedUser = await this.userModel.findOne({ firebaseId: firebaseId?.trim() });
    if (fetchedUser == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return UserDto.fromDocument(fetchedUser);
}

async create(createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<UserDto> {
    const now = new Date();

    const userToCreate = UserDto.fromCreateUserDto(createUserDto);
    userToCreate.createdAt = now;
    userToCreate.personId = ""; //@TODO

    const createdUser = await new this.userModel(userToCreate).save();

    return UserDto.fromDocument(createdUser);
}

async delete(id: string): Promise<boolean> {
    try {
        const result = await this.userModel.findByIdAndDelete(id);
        return !!result;
    } catch (error) {
        return false;
    }
}

async joinOrganization(userId: string, joinOrganizationDto: JoinOrganizationDto): Promise<UserDto> {
    const updatedUser = await this.userModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
        userId,
        {
            $addToSet: { organizationIds: joinOrganizationDto.organizationId },
        },
        { new: true },
    );

    return updatedUser ? UserDto.fromDocument(updatedUser) : null;
}
```

}